Implicit differentiation of $\frac{x^2}{x^2-y^2}=3y$
I want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $\frac{x^2}{x^2-y^2}=3y$. This is what I have tried:

Method 1, Initial product rule
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{x^2-y^2}&=3y\\
x^2&=3y\left(x^2-y^2\right)\\
x^2&= 3x^2y-3y^3\\
\frac{d}{dx}x^2&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2y-3y^3\right)\\
2x&=6xy+3x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-9y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\left(2x-6xy\right)&=\left(3x^2-9y^2\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{2x-6xy}{3x^2-9y^2}
\end{align}
$$

Method 2, Initial quotient rule
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{x^2-y^2}&=\frac{d}{dx}3y\\
\frac{\left(x^2-y^2\right)2x-x^2\left(2x-2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3+2x^2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}+\frac{2x^2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=\left(3-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}{3-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{2x^3-2xy^2-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}{\frac{3\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{-2xy^2}{\cancel{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}}{\frac{3\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2-2x^2y}{\cancel{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=-\frac{2xy^2}{3\left(x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4\right)-2x^2y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=-\frac{2xy^2}{3x^4-6x^2y^2+3y^4-2x^2y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{2xy^2}{2x^2y-3x^4+6x^2y^2-3y^4}
\end{align}
$$

My question / concern:
$$
\frac{2x-6xy}{3x^2-9y^2}\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\frac{2xy^2}{2x^2y-3x^4+6x^2y^2-3y^4}
$$

Edit 1: Fixed step 3 of method 2.
Edit 2: Fixed step 8 of method 2.

Please see my edit.

I've checked all the detailed, the answer should be yes...

\begin{align}\frac{\left(x^2-y^2\right)2x-x^2\left(2x-2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-\color{red}{2x^3}}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}&=\left(3\color{red}{-}\frac{\color{red}{2y}x^2}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\end{align}
Edit: \begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{2x\left(x^2-y^2\right)-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}{3-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\frac{2x^3-2y^{\color{red}{2}}x-2x^3}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}{\frac{3\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}-\frac{2x^2y}{\left(x^2-y^2\right)^2}}\end{align}

(1) In the third line (where you get $(3 + \dots) \frac{dy}{dx}$, I'm not sure I'm seeing how you got that right hand side...it's not what I came up with.
(2) It's possible nonetheless to get two apparently different answers. Consider a case like
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1 
$$
Using implicit diff'n, we get
$$
2x + 2yy' = 0
$$
so
$$
y' = -x/y
$$
But given that $x^2 + y^2= 1$, we cou;d equally well have come up with
$$
y'= -x / \sqrt{1 - y^2}.
$$
(there's a $\pm$ sign missing here, but the gist is the same).
Still, I suspect an error in the algebra back in the line I identified...try writing out a couple more steps between those two.
